# GWT JSON Parse is removing \ character

Tags: java, regex, json, gwt

In GWT, I am trying to provide a regex as an input through JSON and attempting to read it back again. But on reading back the value from JSON, the \ character that I give during input is missed.

```
String input = "{\"digit\":\"(\d*)\"}";

JSONValue  parse   = JSONParser.parseLeneient(input);
JSONObject jsonObj = parse.isObject();

if(jsonObj!=null) {
 for(String key:jsonObj.keySet()) {
    System.out.prinltn(jsonObj.get(key).toString();
 }
}
```

The output that I get is

```
(d*)
```

How do I make the \ character to appear as well in my ouput?

Comment: What is this? ... `String input = {"digit":"(\d*)"};` ... Did GWT extend Java's syntax?

Comment: pardon. that was a typo. corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JSON specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) states

> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
>   family of programming languages.  A string begins and ends with
>   quotation marks.  **All Unicode characters may be placed within the
>   quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped:
>   quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
>   through U+001F).**

A reverse solidus is `\`. **So you can't place a `\` alone in a JSON string.**

Since your parsing is lenient it just ignores the `\`, since `\d` [is not a valid escape sequence.](http://json.org/)

Basically the JSON

```
{
    "digit": "(\d*)"
}
```

is not [valid](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: …and should be written `\\d` (in JSON, so `\\\\d` in Java)

Comment: @thomas No. The String literal \\ will result in a single \ in the JSON which as I stated is invalid. \\\\ will result in \\ which will appear like that in the JSON and doesn't seem to be what OP wants.

Comment: It does look like what he wants: the `\\` in the JSON is an encoding/escaping of a single `\`, when you get the value as a Java (or JS or whatever) string value, you get a `\` character (which, if you serialized your string back to Java, JS, JSON, etc. would have to be written as `\\`), that the RegExp parser will correctly interpret.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Maybe I misunderstood what you are saying. A `String` literal and a `String` value are two different things. I think OP was originally trying to show the content of their JSON which was `{"digit": "(\d*)"}`. They've since edited that and made the code uncompilable. If they did make it compile with `"{\"digit\":\"(\\d*)\"}"`, it would be invalid JSON. If they did `"{\"digit\":\"(\\\\d*)\"}";`, it would be valid JSON, but not what they are looking for (which is not possible).

Comment: My understanding is that it is both valid JSON **and** what they're looking for.